# How to access Redux dispatch in array used to generate React list markup?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

```
const items = [
  {
    Icon: <SecurityIcon />,
    content: 'Activate Account',
    handleClick: () => store.dispatch(openDialog(DIALOG_IDS.ACTIVATION)),
  }
  ...
];

export default function Account() {
  return (
    <>
      {items.map(({ Icon, content, handleClick}) => (
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClick}>
          <ListItemIcon children={Icon} />
          <ListItemContent children={content} />
        </MenuItem>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

My list of `items` contains various objects that contain a `handleClick` property, *some of which* need to dispatch an action against the Redux store.

I am currently importing the store into the component to achieve this, but I have read that this is not recommended. Can someone recommend a better solution? Help appreciated, thanks

Comment: Not sure why do you need a `dispatch` in the Account component. Can you elaborate more? Since each item has a `handleClick` property, you would need dispatch where you are generating the items array. MenuItem is just going to call the handle which was passed.

Comment: I need dispatch since I want my click handler to dispatch an action.

I don't understand what you mean. Your English does not make sufficient sense to me. Can you be a little clearer? Thank you!